# ng-click and jQuery click events not firing inside ng-repeat list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have some funny behavior going on inside a `ul` generated by `ng-repeat`. Here is my code:

```
<li ng-repeat = "Store in Stores" ng-show = "hasSelectedServices(Store)" class="store">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a storeInfo">
            <div class="storeTitle">
                {{"Green Square # " + Store.StoreID}}
            </div>
            <div class = "storeDetails">
                <span class = "gasPrice">{{getGasPrice(Store)}}</span>
                <span class = "storeDistance" ng-show = "haveGPS">{{'  Dist: ' + Store.Distance + ' mi'}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="ui-block-b storeButton" ng-click = "viewStoreDetails(Store)"><i class = "fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is what's confusing me: the `ng-click` function fires as expected for the first few list items but breaks for the rest (I have about 30 items). I also tried binding the `jquery tap` event and even added an inline `onclick` function to each `li` and all solutions exhibit the same behavior. For what it's worth, the first few elements that do work are all in view (i.e. I do not have to scroll down to view them). This is a `phonegap` application with `jquery mobile and angularjs` running on `android`

**EDIT:**

It appears the problem has nothing to do with `ng-click` or the `click` event not firing. Rather, I noticed throughout the app that when I am scrolled down buttons no longer work. In other words I must be scrolled all the way to the top of a page for ANY button to work.

Comment: Well, outside of this, we could use to see some javascript code. What does viewStoreDetails(Store) look like?

Comment: Since it works for some and not breaks for others, there may be an error in the data, or one in the function, rather than with your html

Comment: I think I know the answer but I need to know what kind of error you get?

Comment: @EliteOctagon I changed the function to just console.log('view store') and it is not being called by the later list items

Comment: @AlexChoroshin it is not throwing an error, it's simply not calling the ng-click function

Comment: The above behavior was seen on an android emulator; I've deployed the app to a test device and now all list items are broken (no ng-click firing)

Comment: i think its because of the scope, may be the scope where viewStoreDetails() is defined is not accessible. ng-click will trigger when the scope is accessible  .

Comment: it will be more clear if you mention a jsfiddle

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm having something similarly odd happening in my colleagues browsers but not mine (same version of chrome, etc).

Comment: @Simon the issue in my case was related to scrolling. Try clicking while still at the top of the page (i.e. before doing ANY scrolling), if it works then we have the same issue and you can resolve it by installing a scrolling plugin (I don't recommend jquery-mobile-iscrollview due to known issues with angularjs; consider iscroll or ng-iscroll). If your issue is NOT related to scrolling then not sure!